# Expand Collapse Tree

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a tree list like this :-

```
<ul class="firstLevel">
  <li class="category"> <a href="level1.php">Level 1</a> 
     <ul>
        <li class="category"> <a href="level2.php">Level 2</a>
           <ul>
              <li class="category"><a href="level3.php">Level 3</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="level4.php">Level 4</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="category"><a href="level2a.php">Level 2 a </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The issue is, when I assign a class to the `<li>` then the page reloads the css assigned will be gone since it is going to another page ( I won't be using ajax for this page, it's a page done in the system and changing it will hv to change many other sections, thus for now will have to reload the whole page ).

Below is my js :-

```
$('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
$('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
$('li.category').children().hide();
$("ul.firstLevel li a").css("display", "block");


        $('li.category').each(
            function(column) {
            $(this).click(function(event){

                if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) { 
                //collapse other category and expand its children. 
                   $('li.category').children().hide();

                } else { 
                    $(this).children().hide();
                    $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
                    $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
                }


        });
        }
        );
```

How can I achieve the expand / collapse for the tree view above? There will be many levels. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
$('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
$('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
$('li.category').children().hide();
$("ul.firstLevel li a").css("display", "block");


$('li.category > a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   if($(this).hasClass('minusimageapply')) { 
      //collapse other category and expand its children. 
      $(this).next('ul').hide();
      $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply').addClass('plusimageapply');
   } else { 
      $(this).next('ul').show();
      $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply').addClass('minusimageapply');
   }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/88bta7Le/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However when I clicked on the link, the whole page refreshed and the classes assigned in JS gone. any idea how I can retain the assigned CSS?

Comment: @Sylph Please update my working demo with your code to let me see the full view

Comment: I tried on my localhost, but in fiddle i don't have the static pages to load. When user clicks on the final level, then the page loads, all the category became collapsed. Will I be able to retain that category as expanded?

Comment: @Sylph give its li class="category" and it will work fine

Comment: Thanks again! ya, I added in class="category" then the tree remains expanded. However it doesn't load the page where the <a> links to. 
Almost solved it! thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, but if you can help to let me know how I can make the <a> link clickable and yet remain it as expanded?  Thanks for your great help

Comment: @Sylph I can't got your point .. right now all your tree collapsed and when you click the level it show the next level .. and if you click it again it will hide the next level .. so ?? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/88bta7Le/2/

Comment: ya, the expand and collapse works fine, but the link <a> is not working. As in, with the class="category", clicking on the link will not bring user to the intended page. I believe it's because of the "preventDefault" ? 
If I removed the preventDefault, then the <a> link is working but then all the trees will became collapse.

Comment: In your fiddle, the last <li>  I removed the class="category". http://jsfiddle.net/88bta7Le/3/ 
After clicking on level 4, the tree is gone. How can I make it stay there?

Comment: @Sylph give its li another class name and create click event for its anchor  and use e.preventDefault();  I mean  class="Anothercategory" and make  $('li.Anothercategory > a').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();}

Comment: Thanks again, I will give it a try. Once I got it right I will mark your answer as correct. :) 
As for now I will leave it open first , to get some pointers from others if any. hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @Sylph sure I don't mind with that .. you should get a good solution ... whatever from me or from anyone else .. this final thing I reached http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/88bta7Le/4/

Comment: Actually the only way  I can make the "<a>" link works is to remove the preventDefault. However removing the preventDefault will make all the link back to zero, which is all collapsed. :( 
http://jsfiddle.net/88bta7Le/6/